# Why is the for loop turning into an infinite loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite

Why is the code below resulting in an infinite loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i!=12;i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n",i);
    i=12;
  }
}
```

Comment: `i++` is excecuted at the end of the loop so i will become `i=13`

Comment: ask yourself whether (12+1) == 12 is ever true.

Comment: because after loop operation `i++` is executed so you set `i=12` than you increment it with `i++` and then new iteration is performed which checks if `i!=12`.. I recommend you, if you don't exactly know what the program is doing, use debugger to found out what it is doing.

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Answer (score 2):

Because `i` never equals `12` *when it's checked by the loop*.  You execute `i++` after each loop iteration, so `i` always equals `13` when it's checked.

You can omit the `i++` part entirely, or set `i = 11;` instead to accomplish the same thing.  (Of course, since "the same thing" in this case is only ever wanting a single iteration of the loop, you don't really need a loop in the first place.  But I assume this is just a contrived learning exercise.)

Answer (score 1):

`i++` is excecuted at the end of the loop so `i` will become `13`

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the `for` loop increments the variable before checking the loop condition.

Here's the code with the `for` loop rewritten as a `while` loop:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 void main()
{
  int i;
  i=0;
  while(i!=12)
  {
     printf("%d\n",i);
     i=12;
     i++;
  }
}
```

And here's its output (the first few lines):

```
0
13
13
13
...
```

Each time through the loop, the code sets `i` to 12, and then immediately increments it to 13 before checking the condition and restarting the loop.  The loop will only terminate when `i==12`, so it will run forever.